# Filter Out Branch in Git when Cloning

Tags: git, file, clone, git-filter-branch

I have a large repository that I am trying to clone, but there seems to be a few PSD files that have been added that I can't avoid at the current moment. I have a specific path on the repository that I want to checkout but I'm having trouble figuring out what specific command I need to follow.

I was told filter-branch is what I need to leverage but I'm unsure how to use it.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the man page to [git-filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).
If you don't need the checkins after those PSD files were pushed, it might be easier to [git-checkout](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) the version right before.